# How do I create a 'fatjar' in multi module selenium automation project?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle

I've been at this for days and have tried many things but I can't seem to figure this out. I'm converting a **multi module project** in intellij from maven to gradle and have a structure as follows:

> com.automation
>
> - build.gradle
> - api
>
>   - src/main/Authorisation.java
>   - src/test/LoginAuth.java
>   - build.gradle
> - pageobjects
>
>   - src/main/LoginPage_Method.java
>   - build.gradle
> - testclasses
>
>   - src/test/LoginTests.java
>   - build.gradle

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
        archiveBaseName = project.jar_name
        zip64 = true

        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'My Main Class'
        }

        from sourceSets.test.output
        from { configurations.testRuntime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        with jar
    }
```

In my `com.automation > build.gradle` file I'm trying to create a fatjar so when I run  `java -jar {nameofJar}.jar` the jar runs as it should.
The problem I think is that when I create the jar file the dependencies are not getting created (I know this because when the jar is extracted I'm not seeing the classpath files) so when I try to run the jar file I get an exception:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

Any help to figure this out is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem. For anyone with the same issue, I replaced :

> from { configurations.testRuntime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it :
>   zipTree(it) } }

with

> from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it
>   : zipTree(it) } }